# How using Table to calculate numerically eigenvalue against two variables (x,y)?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

How using Table to calculate numerically eigenvalue against two variables (x,y)?

Matrix:-

```
r[x_, y_] = ( {
    {Cos[x], Cos[x y]},
    {Sin[x y],   Sin[y]}
   } );
start = 0; end = 10; steb = .002; dmatrex = 2;
j0 = (end - start)/steb + 1;
r0 = Transpose@
   Table[{t, #} & /@ Sort[Eigenvalues[r[t, 0]]], {t, start, end, 
     steb}];
egin0 = Table[r0[[i, j]][[2]], {i, 1, dmatrex}, {j, 1, j0}];
ListLinePlot[egin0[[1]], DataRange -> {0, 10}, 
 Frame -> {True, True, True, True},
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 2, ImageSize -> {400, 500}, 
 Background -> White , LabelStyle -> 12, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Courier", 15, Bold}, 
 ImageMargins -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

How can we calculate the eigenvalue and plot it against two variables in the same way my code

```
r[x_, y_] = ( {
    {Cos[x], Cos[x y]},
    {Sin[x y],   Sin[y]}
   } );
start = 1; end = 3; steb = 1; dmatrex = 2;
j0 = (end - start)/steb + 1;
(r0 = Transpose@
    Table[{x, y, #} & /@ Sort[N[Eigenvalues[r[x, y]]]], {x, start, 
      end, steb}, {y, start, end, steb}]) // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
r[x_, y_] = ({{Cos[x], Cos[x y]}, {Sin[x y], Sin[y]}});
start = 1; end = 3; steb = .1; dmatrex = 2;
j0 = (end - start)/steb + 1;
r0 = Transpose@
   Flatten[Table[{x, y, #} & /@ Sort[N[Eigenvalues[r[x, y]]]], {x, 
      start, end, steb}, {y, start, end, steb}], 1];
ListPlot3D[r0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dear Daniel Huber it was really helpful. How can I extract this data into an Excel file

Comment: To save an EXCEL file, try e.g.: `Export["d://mp//t1//test.csv", r0, "XLS"]`